# Bootstrap Popover will not work when it is dynamically loaded

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, popover

I have three files related to the issue, will only give the essential parts of the code:

1. daily_events_page.html file:

```
<div class="container" id="main-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Back</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10" id="main-table">
        <!--dynamic table to be inserted here-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Book Event</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2. daily_events_page.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main-table').load(link)
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').on("hover", function () {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            title: "Actions for this Event",
            placement: top
        })
    })
})
```

of which the link variable leads to my php file to query the sql db

3. daily_events_page.php file:

```
    if ($eventResult->num_rows > 0) {
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $eventResult->num_rows) {
            $row = $eventResult->fetch_assoc();
            $daily_event .= '<tr class="each-event" data-toggle="popover" 
                             data-content="Some content"><td>' . 
                             $row["event_name"] . '</td>';
            $daily_event .= '<td>' . $row["status"] . '</td>';
            $daily_event .= '<td>' . $row["day_of_week"] . '</td>';
            $daily_event .= '<td>' . $row["week_of_year"] . '</td>';
            $daily_event .= '<td>' . $row["event_year"] . '</td>';
            $daily_event .= '<td>' . $row["start_time"] . '</td>';
            $daily_event .= '<td>' . $row["end_time"] . '</td>';
            $daily_event .= '<td>' . $row["machine_group"] . '</td>';
            $daily_event .= '</tr>';
            $i += 1;
        }
    }
```

The table loads with the information I need from the SQL DB, but the popover function does not work.
How do I make the popover appear in the dynamically loaded table such that a hover action over a row would display the popover with the message "Some content"?

Comment: Well it should probably start with _reading_ the value of that `data-content` attribute.

Comment: Hi @04FS, would you mind elaborating more on the _reading_ part?